# Getting Json Data C#

Tags: c#, json

I have a function where I can get all JSON data from but I do not understand how to pick out specific data.

I am using dynamic variable to loop thought all JSON information.

How can I for example pick out all "names:" from the given JSON URL and display it in the console.

Fetching data with url:

```
    public string FetchData(string url)
    {
        string String_jsonData;

        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            Uri SourceUri = new Uri(url);

            String_jsonData = client.DownloadString(SourceUri);
        }
        return String_jsonData;
    }
```

Main and run methode,

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        p.run();
        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    public void run()
    {
        string url = "JSON URL;

        dynamic pers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(FetchData(url));

        // fetching all data. Here I want to select specific data and save it.
        foreach (var item in pers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

    }
```

Model Class:

```
class Person
{
    public string name { get; set; }

    public string ci_list { get; set; }
}
```

Here is an example of the data I want to fetch

```
{
"items": [
{
"ci_type": "xxx",
"exists_in_equipman": false,
"exists_in_hydra": false,
"exists_in_taxen": true,
"hns_name": false,
"id": xxx,
"latest_sync_info": {
  "HYDRA": "xxx",
  "TAXEN": "xxx"
},
"modified_url": "xxx",
"name": "xxx",
"params": {
  "Band (4G)": {
    "id": xxx,
    "source": "script",
    "source_name": "xxx",
    "value": {}
  },
  "Hardware Specification": {
    "id": xxx,
    "source": "script",
    "source_name": "taxen_import",
    "value": {
      "0": {
        "3GPP release": {
          "value": ""
        },
        "Accessories": {
          "value": ""
        },
        "Category": {
          "value": ""
        },
        "Hw rev": {
          "value": "xxx"
        },
        "Locked": {
          "value": ""
        },
        "Model family name": {
          "value": "xxxx"
        },
        "Physical state": {
          "value": "xxxx"
        },
        "Serial No": {
          "value": "xxxx"
        },
        "Software": {
          "value": ""
        },
        "Software version": {
          "value": ""
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: Did you try `Console.WriteLine(item.name);`?

Comment: Can you hint as to what the json structure looks like?  Is `name` a top level property?

Comment: Can you provide JSON getting from URL?

Comment: Do not use `WebClient`, it is very old. Use `HttpClient` instead, it is much more modern.

Comment: I have updated with JSon data.

Comment: this JSON you posted, is it the content of part of the `pers` object (i.e. the result of the second FetchData operation)? It's unclear. The JSON is incomplete ("items" is a sub-property of something, but we can't see what the parent looks like). Perhaps you should show the whole JSON that the URL returns then it's clear.

Comment: I have removed some code. Hope it make it more clear. I am fetching from Json URL into the foreach loop. All the data is printing.

The Json data I have in the topic is the beginning of what I get from the fetch of url.

Comment: ok but since we can't see the top level of the JSON, we can't determine how you should access the data in the first instance. It's impossible that the JSON starts with `"items" : [`  - that's the structure of an inner property name of an object. A JSON string cannot begin like that. We need to see the outer structure of the JSON, even if it's just a bracket (`{` I mean) - at least we'd be certain then that the top level is an object containing the "items" property.

Comment: Ok thanks. So I think your issue is that `pers` is not directly an array, it's an object. You need to loop over the "items" property within it (as I was implying in my last comment). Try `foreach (var item in pers.items)`

Comment: Thanks @ADyson it work now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that `pers` is not directly an array, it's an object.

You need to loop over the "items" property which is held within it. This array is what contains the objects which have the "name" properties.

Change your loop code to

```
foreach (var item in pers.items)
```

Answer (score 1):

First get data from `url`

```
var json = string.Empty;

string url = "http://";

using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    json = httpClient.GetStringAsync(url).Result;

}
```

Then Deserialize object (assume is lest of objects)

```
 List<dynamic> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(json);

foreach (var ar in list)
{
   Console.WriteLine(ar["name"]); //assume object look like {"name":"saa", "age":"23"} and want to access name 
}
```

Example in how to extract `ci_type` value based on json object in your question

```
string json = "{\r\n\"items\": [\r\n{\r\n\"ci_type\": \"xxx\",\r\n\"exists_in_equipman\": false,\r\n\"exists_in_hydra\": false\r\n}\r\n]\r\n}";
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
var data  = result["items"];

foreach (var cityType in data)
{
    Console.WriteLine(cityType["ci_type"]);
}
```

result : `xxx`

Comment: Hello. I am getting this error when implementing your solution.

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: Please show me the json data you suppose to deserialize

Comment: Hello. I have posted the beginning part that I want to deserialize in the topic.